# валидация без формы

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли как-то сделать валидацию для двух полей на странице которая будет проверять поля на пустоту при нажатии на кнопку без тега `form` и если они пустые выводить сообщение?

```
<label> Об'єкт </label>  
       <input type="text" value="${osdch}" placeholder="Позначення" data-field="osdch" autocomplete>

<label> Виріб </label>  
       <input type="text" value="${kiz}" placeholder="Код виробу" data-field="kiz" autocomplete>


<button id='buildTree' class='btn btnCollor btn-sm btn-success' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Відобразити дерево"> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то можно, например, задать инпутам уникальные id и по клику на кнопку проверять их значения на пустоту:

```js
$('#buildTree').click(function(){
  if($('#obekt').val() == '') {
    alert('Потрібен Об\'єкт');
    $('#obekt').focus();
    return;
  }
  else if($('#vyrib').val() == '') {
    alert('Потрібен Виріб');
    $('#vyrib').focus();
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="obekt"> Об'єкт </label>  
       <input id="obekt" type="text" value="${osdch}" placeholder="Позначення" data-field="osdch" autocomplete>

<label for="vyrib"> Виріб </label>  
       <input id="vyrib" type="text" value="${kiz}" placeholder="Код виробу" data-field="kiz" autocomplete>


<button id='buildTree' class='btn btnCollor btn-sm btn-success' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Відобразити дерево"> Відобразити дерево
</button>
```

Comment: да похоже на правду, теперь осталось придумать как вывести сообщения в виде tooltip-а, спасибо большое